# Get product tabs by product ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

How would you go about getting a product tabs by a product ID?

In the single-product/tabs/tabs.php the following code exists:

```
$tabs = apply_filters('woocommerce_product_tabs', array());
```

I guess this is getting tabs based on the current product? However, I would like to get tabs for other products here as well.

Currently I am having a product that is sold in singles. Then I am having another product that is selling the same item but as a subscription. So I have created a custom field where I am telling WooCommerce what single product this is a subscription of.

And now I want to display the single product tabs at the subscription product as well so I don't have to type it in twice in the admin area.

My own experimenting have resulted in this:

```
$singleProduct = get_field('single_product');

if ($singleProduct->ID) : 
    $tabs = 'How do I get the tabs of this product???';
endif;
```

Comment: say if a `product A` do not have any subscription product then would `product A` will have that tab?

Comment: @RaunakGupta correct, and its tabs should be displayed on product B which is the subscription version of product A. This since a product cannot be both a single product and a subscription product at once.

Answer (score 0):

> First of All you have to add a custom product tab in singles page then
>   you have to query for the content that you want to show in that tab.

Here is the code that will help you:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab');

function woo_new_product_tab($tabs)
{
    global $product;
    //get current product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_ID();
    if (/*add you condition to determine current product will have custom tab or not */)
    {
        // Adds the new tab
        $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
            'title' => __('New Product Tab', 'woocommerce'),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'wh_woo_new_product_tab_content'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

function wh_woo_new_product_tab_content()
{
    global $product;
    //get current product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_ID();
    // Now you have the ID you can apply your custom logic
}
```

Reference : [Add a custom tab](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/#section-5)

Comment: I don't want to add custom tabs. I just want to display another products tabs.

Comment: For example on product ID 11 I want to display product ID 22 tabs since product ID 22 is the single product version of product ID 11 which is the subscription product.

Comment: @JimmieJohansson: yes then also you need to create a tab in product ID 11 page and you must have flag which decide #22 is the product who's data need to be fetched then you can fetch the data of #22 and display them in the custom tab of #11 product page